# how to handle windows base file download pop up and save file with selenium and java?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

```
public static FirefoxProfile FirefoxDriverProfile() throws Exception {
    FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
    profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
    profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",false);
    profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir",Constant.downloadPath);
    profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile",
               "text/csv;application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document");
    profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk",
               "text/csv;application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document");
    profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", false);
    profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.alertOnEXEOpen", false);
    profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.focusWhenStarting", false);
    profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.useWindow", false);
    profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete",false);
    profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.closeWhenDone", false);
    profile.setPreference("pdfjs.disabled", true);

    return profile;
}

@Test
public static synchronized WebDriver getDriverInstance(String browser) throws Exception{
    // If the browser is Firefox, then do this
    if (Constant.BROWSER_FIREFOX.equalsIgnoreCase(browser)) {

        fd = new FirefoxDriver(FirefoxDriverProfile());
        fd.manage().window().maximize();
        fd.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    }
}
```

Above is my code to autodownload file without showing windows pop up but it is not working.
I have taken references from answers given on various sites and stackoverflow. I am new to selenium.

Comment: what is *not working*?

Comment: Fixed the indentation

Answer (score 0):

If that if all your code, I don't understand how do you expect it to download anything. Try using `Robot()` instead of force disable windows. Here is my example of such code:

```
public static void copyPaste (String content) throws AWTException {
    //store the path (that you passing as 'content' String) to the saving folder in RAM
    StringSelection selection = new StringSelection(content);
    Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
    clipboard.setContents(selection, selection);

    //Initialize Robot()
    Robot robot = new Robot();

    //wait some time for save dialog to open
    robot.delay(3000);

    //imitate user's action - paste what you stored in RAM previously
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);

    //submit this and download should start
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
}
```

You can use this method after you opening the download window dialog.